# Why there is no response back from XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm truing to get some results from a PHP file connected to a DB , But the variable that is sent to the DB is not sent from the XMLHttpRequest .

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
```

**Here is the JS:**

```
var uname = document.getElementById('name');
function checkUser(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST" , 'file.php' , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){               
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {                   
            console.log(xhr.responseText);                  
        }               
    }
    var userName = uname.value;
    xhr.send(userName); 
}
uname.addEventListener("blur" , checkUser);
```

**The PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['userName'])){
   echo $_POST['userName'];
}
```

If I remove the condition , I get a message saying that the `userName` Index is not defined.

Comment: Try and change `var userName = uname.value;` to `var userName = 'userName=' + uname.value;`. When passing data to Ajax, you need to use the query format: `fieldname=value&anotherfield=somevalue`. _Note:_ when passing a variable to a function, the variable name isn't passed so the fact that your variable is called `userName` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should do it.

```
var userName = uname.value;
xhr.send("data" + userName);
```

And your PHP should process like this. place it in a variable ($response) in this case and echo the var at the end of your code.

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
$username = $_POST['data'];
} else {
$username = "Data Not Set"}
echo $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment above you are not assigning the POST variable correctly - each should be a `name/value` pair so in this instance you would set the name as `userName` and the value to the value from the form element.

```
function checkUser(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open( 'POST', 'file.php', true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){               
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {                   
            console.log(xhr.responseText);                  
        }              
    }
    /* As the function was bound to the input you can use `this` to get the value */
    xhr.send( 'userName='+this.value ); 
}

var uname = document.getElementById('name');
uname.addEventListener('blur' , checkUser.bind( uname ), false );/* bind function to field */
```

Alternatively a more flexible approach would be a small function that does the ajax requests which can be used for multiple calls without needing to rewrite the same code repeatedly.

```
function ajax( url, params, callback ){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange  = function(){
        if( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) callback.call( this, this.response );
    };
    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send( params );
}



function checkUser(){
    ajax.call( this, 'file.php', 'username='+this.value, function(r){
        console.log( r );
    });
}

var uname = document.getElementById('name');
uname.addEventListener('blur' , checkUser.bind( uname ), false );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add file_get_contents on your php side,

```
    $uname = file_get_contents("php://input");
if(isset($uname)){
   echo $uname;
}
```